# check if office is installed in 64 bit Win OS using registry

Tags: registry, ms-office

I trying to check if office is installed using registry. I am able to verify for 32 bit OS using the following regkey

"..HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot" + "Path"

But how do i check when using a 64 bit OS? This key does not exist on a 64 bit OS for either 32 or 64 bit Office. (Checked on both Win7 & Win 8)

Answer (score 1):

I finally tracked down the answer I was looking for. [This forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/officeitpro/thread/efe946bd-25d0-4a30-9f8d-04ef2624d040) has an answer that suggests some registry keys to try.

Comment: I had raised that question myself after looking around a lot :). And i thot i had posted the link for it over here for reference, a little baffled that it has disappeared

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm) , the registry key needs to be checked in **WOW6432Node**.
So your path would be something like :

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\InstallRoot